# ¿Por qué se usa presente en "que casi me despacha cuando recién llegué"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

> La cagatina que casi **me despacha** cuando recién llegué a Chiloé no
>   fue disentería, porque se me habría quitado con los antibióticos del
>   doctor, sino un maleficio, como demostró Eduvigis al curarme con
>   rezos, con su infusión de arrayán, linaza y toronjil y con sus friegas
>   en la barriga con pasta para limpiar metales.

¿Hay alguna regla o razón para explicar el uso de presente en este acontecimiento del pasado? Estoy perplejo/a en este caso.

Comment: @walen, ¿haces una respuesta, por favor?  Estoy de acuerdo contigo, no se necesita *casi* o *por poco* para narrar una historia en el presente.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Éste parece ser un ejemplo de **[presente de conato](http://www.gramaticas.net/2016/09/ejemplos-de-presente-de-conato.html)** (o **presente conativo**), que expresa "una acción que tendría lugar en el pasado pero que no llegó a realizarse." No es lo mismo que presente histórico o narrativo. Varias [gramáticas españolas](http://journals.lub.lu.se/ojs/index.php/rhe/article/view/15495/13992) lo han reconocido y lo caracterizan por el uso de frases adverbiales como *casi* o *por poco*.

En el presente de conato se expresa una acción que, de haber ocurrido, habría aparecido en pretérito. De la presencia de esos adverbios característicos el oyente deduce que la acción no ocurrió, o no se completó: *casi me despacha*, *por poco me mata del susto*, etc. Hay unas cuantas variantes, pero, me parece, no muchas, y quizá estirando la definición del tiempo verbal: *un poco más y se me escapa*, por ejemplo.

Hasta ahí lo que dicen los estudiosos. En lo personal yo noto desde siempre que muchas veces hay una vacilación en el uso del presente de conato, debida justamente a que se habla en presente del indicativo de una acción pasada hipotética, que lleva a algunos hablantes a optar por el uso de una negación explícita que, analizada de manera estrictamente lógica junto con el otro adverbio, invierte su sentido: *por poco no me caigo*, *casi no me atropellan*. En realidad la lógica no funciona aquí y la frase significa lo mismo con y sin el *no* (!).

En algún punto de este proceso dejamos de tratar con presente de conato; ya que si en vez de *por poco* usamos *por un pelo* la negación se vuelve obligatoria.

Comment: Muy interesante la idea del "presente de conato", no la conocía.

Answer (score 2):

El concepto de "presente de conato" resulta interesante y creo que va en la buena dirección de reflejar los usos actuales del idioma.

Sin embargo, es cierto que la RAE no recoge ese tiempo verbal. Lo más parecido, si no queremos salirnos de la gramática oficial, sería el [presente narrativo](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SefbXfWzBHZaBHiz):

> Llaman algunos autores PRESENTE NARRATIVO al empleado como recurso estilístico en las narraciones para describir hechos pasados que se desean mostrar como si fueran actuales. El presente narrativo concurre a menudo con otros tiempos del pasado, de forma que destaca entre ellos y otorga mayor viveza a la narración.

Por mi parte y tras ver los ejemplos que da la RAE, estoy de acuerdo en que el supuesto "presente de conato" debería ser un tiempo verbal distinto, que espero que la RAE recoja en alguna revisión de su Gramática.